# Is it possible to fix the final appearance of a page, after a few animations?

Tags: jquery, html, animation

This may be an over-hopeful question, but I have just started learning jquery (also js beginner) - so I don't know what I don't know.  (Therefore all constructive advice welcomed!)

I built my 1st jquery animation - view (safely) at 
https://ss.smile-nz.com/~qenew1/test2.php.  I sequentially display 3 images representing product lines, shrink and move them to a row down the page.

I really want the after-animation state (the 3 shrunk images in a row etc.) to be the default, so that if the user moves to another page in the website, and then comes back to this page, the animation doesn't rerun.

Without using cookies.

I had thought of building this end state as the beginning state, but hidden - and then running animations to end up with that state ... but this seems a lot of work, so is there a better way?

***HTML***

```
    <div id="outer-box">
    <div class="myContent">
        <div id="hdr">#HMAINS#</div>
        <script> /***  remove 'logo' text from menu **/
            document.getElementById('hdr').getElementsByTagName('td')[4].innerHTML = "";
        </script>
        <div class="box">#CONTENT#</div>
    </div>

    <div class="showImg image1">
        <h4>Aquaculture</h4>
        <img id="startNow" src="images/oceanforest3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="showImg image2">
        <h4>Fishing</h4>
        <img src="images/Pearl-in-shell_square3.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="showImg image3">
        <h4>Industrial</h4>
        <img src="images/temp.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

***Jquery***

```
    $("#startNow").load(function () {
    $(".image1 img").delay(500).animate({opacity: op},{duration: d});
    $(".image1").delay(500).animate( {left: '100px', top: t, height: h, width: w},
        {duration: d, complete: function () {

            $(".image1 h4").css({ "visibility": "visible"});
            $(".image2 img").animate({ opacity: op }, { duration: d });
            $(".image2").animate( {left: '450px', top: t, height: h, width: w},
                {duration: d, complete: function () {

                    $(".image1 h4").css({ "color": "#000000" });
                    $(".image2 h4").css({ "visibility": "visible" });
                    $(".image3 img").animate({ opacity: op }, { duration: d });
                    $(".image3").animate( {left: '800px', top: t, height: h, width: w},
                            { duration: d, complete: function () {

                                $(".image2 h4").css({ "color": "#000000" }); 
                                $(".image3 h4").css({ "visibility": "visible", "color": "#000000" }); 
                            }}                                      
                    );
                }}
            );
        }}
    );
});
```

Comment: I don't know if this will work but you can try to use this -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation , pass an event through the function and inside of it do a condition after animation loads 1 time stopPropagation

Comment: you could use localStorage or sessionStorage - but this is pretty similar to cookies, so might not work for you

Comment: localStorage looks good, my objection to cookies was 'cos I didn't want to bother the user by getting permission; and wouldn't work with cookies turned off.

My thinking now is that this is a splash page, so I will look at using localStorage to redirect in an SEO-acceptable way ... in the normal home page check localStorage and run the splash if it hasn't run before, and the menu & refreshing will go to the real home page.

Haven't a clue how to do this yet :-)

Answer (score 0):

This was looking way too hard, so I did it by having 2 pages - the 'splash page' with the animations, and a 'perm' page that copied the final state of the splash page.  Then some php code to ensure the splash page runs only once, using local storage ....